# JS regular expression confusion

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

Firstly apologies for being a tad dim. I need to create a test to check the if the value of an input field.

I currently use `/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/.test(document.form.Serial.value)` to test to see if the value of Serial is alphanumeric only.

Now, if an additional field is set, Serial must either being with 'i' or 'I', then the remaining characters must all be numbers. I had considered doing this with substrings, but it seems a bit long and unnecessary.

Any advice people can give would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Could you supply some input and expected output?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test if a string begins with i or I, and then only contain numbers, you could use a regular expression such as this one :

```
/^[iI][0-9]+$/
```

Or, for a case-insensitive match :

```
/^i[0-9]+$/i
```

Basically, this will match :

- Beginning of string : `^`
- an `i`
- any character between 0 and 9 : `[0-9]`

  - one or more time : `[0-9]+`
- end of string : `$`

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, I now have a much better idea of how to code similar problems should I encounter them! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try the code below

```
var test_value = false
if (document.form.Additional_Field.value) {
   test_value = /^(i|I)[0-9]+/.test(document.form.Serial.value) }
else {
    test_value = /[A-Za-z0-9]+/.test(document.form.Serial.value) }
```

it will result in **test_value** set to **true** if **Serial** is either alphanumeric or if **Additional_Field** has value true and **Serial** begins with **i** or **I** fallowed by any number of numbers, and **test_value** set to **false** otherwise.

Comment: Would be neater to use the if to store the right regex in a variable, and after the if just run the test with that regex. This way it is redundant. Still, +1.

Comment: I used this code to solve the problem, al be it slightly modified:      `test_value = /^(i|I)[0-9]+$/.test(document.starterForm.Serial.value);
     if (test_value == false)`

Comment: The `(i|I)` is better written as: `[iI]` which is faster.

Comment: It is faster in JS or in general?

Comment: @MP?kalski: In general, faster for _any_ NFA regex engine; e.g. JavaScript, PHP, Ruby, .NET, Java, Perl, Apache mod_rewrite, etc. Alternation for multiple individual characters is what character classes are for. Note that some regex engines may be smart enough to recognize this pattern and automatically optimize it. For more on crafting an accurate and efficient (i.e. _fast_) regex, [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!") is a must read.

Answer (score 0):

Why not break the problem down. You have two valid inputs, so a pattern for syntactically checking the input would be:

```
/^([iI][0-9]+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+)$/
```

Then you have a separate, and simpler, problem of determining whether the validated input is appropriate based on the state of the other controls on the form.